# What Result Should It Return?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this VB script. I don't know as to what result will this yield ?

```
expressao = "Format(#30/04/2015#,""Short Date"")<=Format(#01/05/2015#,""Short Date"")"
        Debug.Print "Resultado 6: " & Eval(expressao)
```

I changed the above snippet code wee bit but, it still brings the same result: false (0):

```
expressao = "Format(#30/04/2015#,""dd/mm/yyyy"")<=Format(#01/05/2015#,""dd/mm/yyyy"")"
Debug.Print "Resultado 8: " & Eval(expressao)
```

this is the final code that tests the value of any form control with the ValidationRule of the respective control's bound field. you set the ValidationRule just once in the form source table and use this ValidationRule to test each control before you save the recordset changes. if it passes the test nothing happens but if it fails, you can show the ValidationText to the user and SetFocus to the respective control for the due changes.

```
Private Function TestarValidationRule(tela As Form, campoTestado As Control) As Variant
    'Author: Alex Borges
    'Location: Rio de Janeiro, Brazil
    'With the help of Adrian and Mat
    On Error GoTo ErroGeral
    Dim registro As DAO.Recordset
    Dim regraValidacao As Variant
    Dim textoValidacao As Variant
    Dim resultado As Variant
    Dim mensagem As String
    Dim expressao As String

    Set registro = tela.Recordset

    regraValidacao = registro.Fields(Right(campoTestado.Name, Len(campoTestado.Name) - 4)).ValidationRule
    textoValidacao = registro.Fields(Right(campoTestado.Name, Len(campoTestado.Name) - 4)).ValidationText

    'Campo sem regra de validação
    If ((regraValidacao & "") = "") Then
        GoTo Erro1

    'Campo com regra de validação
    Else
        Select Case VarType(campoTestado.Value)
            Case vbString
                expressao = """" & CStr(campoTestado.Value) & """" & regraValidacao
                expressao = Replace(expressao, "And ", "And """ & CStr(campoTestado.Value) & """")
                expressao = Replace(expressao, "Or ", "Or """ & CStr(campoTestado.Value) & """")
            Case vbDate
                expressao = "#" & Format(campoTestado.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#" & regraValidacao
                expressao = Replace(expressao, "And ", "And #" & Format(campoTestado.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
                expressao = Replace(expressao, "Or ", "Or #" & Format(campoTestado.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
                expressao = Replace(expressao, "Now()", "#" & Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
        End Select

        resultado = Null
        resultado = Eval(expressao)

        If (resultado = -1) Then
            TestarValidationRule = vbSim

        'Se campo não passou na regra de validação
        ElseIf (resultado = 0) Then
            'Campo deveria ter texto de validação, mas, não tem
            If ((textoValidacao & "") = "") Then
                    mensagem = MsgBox("Este campo deveria apresentar instruções de preenchimento já que não passou no teste de validação." & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & _
                        "Favor, informar ao desenvolvedor do sistema.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Validação do Campo")
            Else
                mensagem = MsgBox(textoValidacao, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Validação do Campo")
            End If

            campoTestado.SetFocus
            TestarValidationRule = vbNao

        'Se teste gerou um resultado inesperado
        Else
            GoTo ErroGeral
        End If
    End If

Sair:
    Set registro = Nothing
    Exit Function
ErroGeral:
    TestarValidationRule = CVErr(513)
    GoTo Sair
Erro1:
    'Resultado de campo sem regra de validação
    TestarValidationRule = Null
    GoTo Sair
End Function
```

Comment: That wee bit is *still* comparing `String` values. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29982274/1188513).

Comment: it doen't work anyway. Eval converts Format result to date so it's not true that it's comparing strings.

Comment: `?typename(Format(#30/04/2015#,"dd/mm/yyyy"))` outputs `String` in the immediate pane. I don't know what `Eval` does, but the `Format` function is defined in the `VBA.Strings` module, so yes, it's comparing strings.

Comment: that's not what MSDN says.

Comment: [that's what the language specs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200137.aspx)

Comment: just run a test and you'll see how it really works. but anyway, we are comparing date literals inside Eval function and the wrong result persists.

Comment: Well look at that. I suggest you take your working code over to [codereview.se] for a peer review, there are a number of issues and redundancies in this code - addressing them would make the code cleaner, easier to maintain and more efficient. Code review can help you get rid of these `GoTo` jumps! :)

Comment: those "a lot of 3" GoTo jumps ensure the good functioning of my system. it is even more accurate and, up to the moment, mistake-proofing. where do you see redundancies? show me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76725/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-thor-my).

Answer (score 3):

It's returning `False` because you're not comparing dates - you're comparing the results of `Format` calls, which return `String` values.

And `"30*" <= "01*"` is `False`.

Remove the `Format` to compare date literals instead, and heck, use a sortable date format:

```
expressao = "#2015-04-30# <= #2015-05-01#"
```

Comment: hi Mat. I started my tests doing what you said, comparing just the dates without Format but, I brings a false result.                                    expressao = "#30/04/2015#<=#01/05/2015#"

Comment: but not to me. it still returns false. i would like to share my print screen.

Comment: expressao = "#2015-04-30# <= #2015-05-01#"    =>    it returns "Resultado 5: 0"

Comment: ok Mat. expressao = "#2015/04/30# <= #2015/05/01#" now is returning true! he problem is that the dates come from the table field's ValidationRule. I'd have to change the format to yyyy/mm/dd and the only way to do that, as far as I know, is via Format function.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by several, your original:

```
expressao = "Format(#30/04/2015#,""Short Date"")<=Format(#01/05/2015#,""Short Date"")"
```

will never Work. For two reasons:

1. You compare strings and not dates.
2. Your syntax for the date values are wrong

Syntax must be either mm/dd/yyyy or - preferred - yyyy/mm/dd.

If you use dd/mm/yyyy, Access is clever enough to figure out that 30/04/2015 should be read as 04/30/2015.

So follow Mat:

```
expressao = "#2015-04-30# <= #2015-05-01#"
```

This will never fail.

Comment: Sorry for the recap, but it doesn't sound like you understand why it doesn't work even after Mat showed you how to do.

Comment: to me there's no need to say sorry if you want to recap something but, why did you delete my last post? did you find anything offensive in it?

Comment: Eh ..? I don't delete comments ... can't even do.

Comment: well, I don't know what rules the administrators follow (or even if they have one) but strange things happen here like my post being deleted mysteriously. I say sorry to you for the wrong affirmation. did you look the final code I posted above? with this code I can set the validation rules as their respective validation texts in the table setup and then test the form controls' value programmatically. if you find any mistake I'd appreciate if you let me know. from the time I posted to now I did changes trying to improve even more.

Comment: Yes. As commented below, you have reverted to the invalid dd/mm/yyyy syntax for the date expressions - and the conversion to yyyy/mm/dd is superflous. You could just as well have used the format yyyymmdd but, still, dates should be handled like dates, not strings or integers, no exceptions. As mentioned several times, the solution by Mat is to the point: expressao = "#2015-04-30# <= #2015-05-01#"

Comment: the date format that comes from the validation rule field, in the table settings, is already mm/dd/yyyy. so, for what reason should I change the date format to yyyy-mm-dd ? again. my local date format is dd/mm/yyyy. but once I type dd/mm/yyyy in the validation rule field (in the table settings), Access, which is clever according to you, converts dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy, am I clear? so, again, why would I convert all the dates, even the validation rule dates, to yyyy-mm-dd ? give a clever answer as Access do, according to you.

Comment: Because your local date format is not used in neither VBA nor Access SQL - actually it is totally ignored except for display when using formats like "Short Date".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are confused as to why it is returning 0? This is because in vba 0=false, -1=true. If this assumption is correct then to get false in this case use the following:

```
Debug.Print "Resultado 6: " & cbool(Eval(expressao))
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: Ok, this is a funny one, ## seems to format a date to dd/mm/yyyy but the funny part is that if you `debug.print #01/05/2015#` the output is 05/01/2015 which is why it ends up being false. remove the ##...

For further information on this look at:
http://www.vb123.com/Pages/kb/200309_ds_aa.aspx

It's rather long but seems to explain it better than I can at the moment.

Comment: hello Adrian. I know that -1 is true and 0 is false. what I don't know is why this expression is returning false (0) when it was suppose to return true (-1). thanks for your assistance. date 1 is earlier than date 2.

Comment: my local date format is dd/mm/yyyy, different from American format that is mm/dd/yyyy. i suspect that this is interfering someway. that's why i added the Format(date, "Short Date"), unsuccessfully. date 1 comes from the form control and date 2 comes from the table field's ValidationRule. maybe date 1 format is dd/mm/yyyy but date 2 is mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: #date# converts to mm/dd/yy.

Comment: if both dates are being converted to mm/dd/yy why does it still brings false result? what I want to compare is (30-Apr-2015 <= 01-May-2015). this should return true not false. the same for (04/30/15 <= 05/01/15).

Comment: hmm, 30/04/2015 isn't being converted it would seem.

Comment: when I run Format(#30/04/2015#,""dd/mm/yyyy"") it brings 30/04/2015, when I run Format(#30/04/2015#,""mm/dd/yyyy"") it brings 04/30/2015 so its being converted yes.

Comment: Yeah but #01/05/2015# is being converted to 05/01/2015 and #30/04/2015# is staying 30/04/2015. 30/04/2015 is greater than 05/01/2015!

Comment: no. both are being converted to me. 01/05/2015 to 05/01/2015 and 30/04/2015 to 04/30/2015

Comment: yes Adrian. and expressao = "#30/04/2015# <= #01/05/2015#" still returns false.

Comment: ok, try this ? datevalue("30/04/2015")<=datevalue("01/05/2015")